# Get distance in Symfony

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony

I try to use a little function for getting the distance between 2 destinations over the Googleapi.

If i try this script without symfony, it works perfekt, but in Symfony i got the following error:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$duration in    
/var/www/symfony/src/123/DepBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 217
```

I call it from the following Action:

```
public function getDepartmentAction()
{
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    $response = $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $locationid = $response->request->get( 'locationid' );
    $userselection = $response->request->get( 'userselection' );

    $niederlassungsrepo = $em->getRepository( 'MbsNiederlassungBundle:Niederlassung' );
    $niederlassung = $niederlassungsrepo->findOneById( $locationid );

        $bezeichnung = $niederlassung->getBezeichnung();
        $strasse = $niederlassung->getStrasse();
        $plz = $niederlassung->getPlz();
        $ort = $niederlassung->getOrt();
        $telefonbuero = $niederlassung->getTelefonbuero();

        $link = $this->generateUrl('_niederlassung', array('filiale' => $bezeichnung));

    $distance = $this->getDistance( $userselection, $plz );   <====== here i wanna call it

    $result = array("bezeichnung" => $bezeichnung,
                    "strasse" => $strasse,
                    "plz" => $plz,
                    "ort" => $ort,
                    "telefonbuero" => $telefonbuero,
                    "link" => $link,
                    "entfernung" => $distance['distance']);


    $encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizer = [new GetSetMethodNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);

    $newData = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');

    return new Response($newData);
}
```

The function where i try to return the distance:

```
private function getDistance($start,$end)
{
    $from = urlencode($start);
    $to = urlencode($end);

    $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=de-de&sensor=false");
    $data = json_decode($data);

    $time = 0;
    $distance = 0;

    foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
        $time += $road->duration->value;            <=======   Line 217
        $distance += $road->distance->value;
    }

    $result['time'] = $time / 60;
    $result['distance'] = $distance / 1000;

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your passing variables `$start` and `$end`.

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$duration in
>   /var/www/symfony/src/123/DepBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 217

It means GoogleMaps Api doesnt find any ties between origins and destinations by your request query ( `$start` and `$end` ) and return  stdClass object with empty properties (`duration` and `distance` are non-existent) . Of course, you catching exception   about undefined property (`duration`).

After JSON data decoding try check on empty properties of response object ( `destination_addresses` or  `origin_addresses` , for example ).